# Excel macro copy columns from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook: "Check for logging". From where I want to copy column "A" and paste it in workbook: "Unit test template". In column "A".

I have been trying to use following code:

```
Private Sub CopyColumnsButton_Click()

Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Check for logging.xlsm").Worksheets("Parameters").Columns("A")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Unit test template.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

End Sub
```

Though every time I attempt to run the macro, I get a message saying: "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" and then this line is highlighted:

```
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Unit test template.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
```

Both workbooks are open when I attempt to run the macro.

I would be very thankfull if anyone could help

Comment: Your code "works on my machine" (with test workbooks, of course). Do you have any special settings in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".

It is mostly unable to find one of the two "Unit test template.xlsm" or "Sheet1" within the workbook.

**Workbook issue..**
1. Check if the file name is "Unit test template.xls**x**" (not .xls**m**)
2. Check if the file "Unit test template.xlsm" is open in the same session as "Check for logging.xlsm" (If Ctrl+Tab doesn't take you to the next workbook, that means they are open in two different session of Excel Application)
3. The Filename is slightly off.

**Worksheet issue..**
1. Check if "Sheet1" was deleted. So it could actually be "Sheet2" etc...

Comment: Thank you, It was because the two workbooks weren't in the same session.